# Banner rotating images. Each image when clicked sends to a different URL (vanilla javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, function

I've been given two examples of how to do this but neither is doing both things that I'm looking to do. My website should include:

- Rotating Image Banner (3 images), that changes every few seconds
- Each image should be clickable and redirect you to a different URL

In our recent lecture, the professor wrote this code on the board and said that this was how you did that. However, it's not working for me.

```
<html>
 <head>
     <script language=JAVASCRIPT type=TEXT/JAVASCRIPT>
     //I'm not sure when to use '' or ""
     //I replaced some of the "picture.jpg" images with links to images. I'm not sure if I used the right syntax. 
     adImages = new Array("https://i.picsum.photos/id/666/800/200.jpg", 
                          "https://i.picsum.photos/id/420/800/200.jpg", 
                          "https://i.picsum.photos/id/888/800/200.jpg");
 adURL = new Array("https://google.com","https://github.com","https://stackoverflow.com");
 thisAd = 0;
 //length of what?
 imgCt = adImages.length;

 function rotate()
 {
  if (document.images)
  {
    thisAd++;
    //Is it better practice to use "==="?
    if (thisAd == imgCt)
    {
      thisAd = 0;
    }
    document.adBanner.src=adImages[thisAd];
      setTimeout("rotate()", 2 * 1000);
  }
 }

 function newLocation()
 {
  document.location.href = adURL[thisAd];
 } 
 </script>
 </head>
     //I don't understand what this is at all
     <body onload=rotate()>
         //Apparently <center> is obsolete?
         <center>
             <p><font size=4>Rotating Banner <font color=#ff0000>Assignment 6</font> Rotate Party - 
             Udemy</font> 
             </p>
         <a href="javascript:newLocation()"><IMG height=105 alt="Ad Banner" 
         src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/666/800/200.jpg" width=610 name=adBanner></a>
         </center>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Just a heads up. I've been posting my slides from class on Reddit the past couple of weeks and I've received a lot of comments about things being horribly out of date. If you can, **please give me examples that are more modern or better practices than what you see me learning**. You can find the conversations about my experience learning JavaScript in community college here if you're interested: https://www.reddit.com/user/gettupled/

The second example we were given was a YouTube video that gave the following example. However, it does not include the option of clicking the image and being sent to a URL. I'm not sure if it's common to post HTML, CSS and Javascript code in the body of a message so I'll just attach a codepen unless told otherwise. This code comes from Travesy Media.

https://codepen.io/vitalwheat/pen/QWbEyqN

Thanks everyone. This is my first post here. Hi.

Comment: Hello @WheatimasMaximas, your code works fine for me. The images are changing every 2 seconds and redirecting to the specified urls when clicked upon.

Comment: Thank you @AkashBhardwaj. I saw that. I was right clicking the image to try to open it in another tab. I think that is what was causing my issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to implement this. Here is one of the way to do it.

[working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-architecture-yz310)

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  const imageList = [
    "https://i.picsum.photos/id/666/800/200.jpg",
    "https://i.picsum.photos/id/420/800/200.jpg",
    "https://i.picsum.photos/id/888/800/200.jpg"
  ];

  const urlList = [
    "https://google.com",
    "https://github.com",
    "https://stackoverflow.com"
  ];

  function createRotatingBanner(rotationTime) {
    const $adsBanner = document.querySelector(".adBanner");
    let $bannerList;

    let currentBannerRendered = 0;

    function renderBanner() {
      Array.from($bannerList).forEach((banner, bannerIndex) => {
        banner.className = bannerIndex === currentBannerRendered ? "" : "hide";
      });
      currentBannerRendered = (currentBannerRendered+1)%$bannerList.length;
    }

    // creating Banner image and setting them to hide
    function createBanner() {
      const fragement = new DocumentFragment();

      imageList.forEach((image, index) => {
        const banner = document.createElement("img");
        banner.src = image;
        // wrapping image with anchor element
        const anchor = document.createElement("a");
        anchor.href = urlList[index];
        // hide all the banner
        anchor.className = "hide"
        anchor.appendChild(banner);
        fragement.appendChild(anchor);
      });
      const cloneFragement = [...fragement.children];
      $adsBanner.appendChild(fragement);
      return cloneFragement;
    }

    $bannerList = createBanner();
    renderBanner();

    setInterval(renderBanner, rotationTime);
  }

  createRotatingBanner(2000);
})();
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="adBanner"></div>
```